# Ruby 2.2.0 won't run because of issue with libgmp.10.dylib

Tags: ruby, macos

I just installed Ruby 2.2.0 with RVM, and trying to use it gives me this:

```
$ rvm use 2.2.0 --default
Using /Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/brandon/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby
  Reason: Incompatible library version: ruby requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libgmp.10.dylib provides version 12.0.0
```

Answer (score 10):

I thought it was going to be a little more involved, but a simple

```
brew upgrade gmp
```

fixed the problem.